Electric potential of two connected metal spheres
I'm having some trouble understading the following problem: "Two metal spheres, with radius $R_{a}$ and $R_{b}$, with $R_{a} > R_{b}$, are connected by a metalic wire with negligible capacitance. The distance between its centers is $d$, where $d \gg R_{a}$. The system has a liquid charge $Q$, distributed between the spheres. What is the electric potential at the surface of the spheres? Assume $V = 0$ at infinity."
The answer is: $V = \frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_{0}}\cdot \frac{Q}{R_{a} + R_{b}}$,
and I know that the following is a solution to the problem:
The surface of the spheres are equipotential, so,
$$
V = V_{a} = V_{b},
$$
where $V_{a}$ and $V_{b}$ are the electric potentials at the surface of the sphere $a$ and $b$, respectively.
Knowing that the spheres are far separated apart, we can consider them as point charges, so the potential of spheres $a$ and $b$ are given by,
$$
V_{a} = \frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_{0}}\frac{Q_{a}}{R_{a}} = \frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_{0}}\frac{Q_{b}}{R_{b}} = V_{b},
$$
so we have the relation,
$$
\frac{Q_{a}}{R_{a}} = \frac{Q_{b}}{R_{b}},
$$
but $Q = Q_{a} + Q_{b}$, so,
$$
\frac{Q_{a}}{R_{a}} = \frac{Q - Q_{a}}{R_{b}},
$$
and after a little math, we find that $Q_{a} = \frac{R_{a}}{R_{a} + R_{b}}Q$, and substituting this on the potential of sphere $a$, we get,
$$
V = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_{0}}\frac{Q}{R_{a} + R_{b}}
$$
Apart from all this, I'm having trouble to understand why can we consider the potential of sphere $a$, as the potential of a non-connected sphere? Because I thought on the following situation: if we think the sphere $a$ is alone, with charge $Q_{a}$, the potential at its surface would be $V_{a} = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_{0}}\frac{Q_{a}}{R_{a}}$, with the respective electric field of a point charge outside the sphere. But when it is connected to the other with charge $Q_{b}$, there will be a charge redistribution, and consequently, the electric field around $a$ will change, so the potential, and then it will not be the potential of a point charge anymore.

$V_{a} = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_{0}}\frac{Q_{a}}{R_{a}}\Rightarrow V_{a} = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_{0}}\frac{Q}{R_{a}+R_{b}}$ and this is equal to $V_b$ by the same reasoning.  Both at the same potential and so when connected together nothing changes.
